# what exactly the fileWriter works in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, filewriter

I use HTML5's filesystem feature in my project. And try to write text append to a file **continuously** by using for-loop. But actually it just effect **one write** which is the last write, even though I got **5 "Write completed."**(That should means it success writing 5 times). Here is my code:

```
window.requestFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
var fs;

function initFS() {
    console.log("init filesystem")
    window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024 * 1024, function (filesystem) {
        fs = filesystem;
        console.log(fs);
    }, errorHandler);
}

function errorHandler(e) {
    var msg = '';
    switch (e.code) {
        ...
    };
    console.log('Error: ' + msg);
}

function receiveFile(cont) {
    fs.root.getFile('log.txt', {
        create: true
    }, function (fileEntry) {
        // Create a FileWriter object for our FileEntry (log.txt).
        fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {
            fileWriter.seek(fileWriter.length);
            fileWriter.onwriteend = function (e) {
                console.log('Write completed.');
            };
            fileWriter.onerror = function (e) {
                console.log('Write failed: ' + e.toString());
            };
            // Create a new Blob and write it to log.txt.
            var bb = new Blob([cont]);
            fileWriter.write(bb);
        }, errorHandler);
    }, errorHandler);
}

function foo() {
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        setTimeout(function () { // // it works, BTW: Why it didn't write the num in ascending order as expected
            (function (x) {
                receiveFile(x);
            })(i)
        }, i * 1000);
        //receiveFile(i); // didn't work, just write once
    }
}

window.addEventListener("load", initFS, false);
```

You can try it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xsuii/QTwLP/10/) and get **result** from this link:  *filesystem:http://fiddle.jshell.net:0/temporary/*

I am thinking about whether if it write so fast that can not be save in time. So I try **'setTimeout'** on it and it works and write completely.

Anyone know why?. How I can implement what I want? Appreciate first if you can help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fileWriter.write()` is an asynchronous operation. You basically created a race here.
What happens without the timeouts (or even with the timeouts if the writes are slow):

- `receiveFile(0)`
- `fileWriter.seek(fileWriter.length /* == 0 */)`
- `queue write(0)`
- `receiveFile(1)`
- `fileWriter.seek(fileWriter.length /* == 0 */)` - Yeah, still `0` as there was no actual write performed yet.
- `queue write(1)`
- ...
- `actual async write(0)`
- `actual async write(1)`
- ...

The rest of what happens is down the implementation details and bugs.
So in conclusion: Always wait for write operations to finish before doing another write.

The current spec draft actually [disallows](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api/#widl-FileWriter-seek-void-long-long-offset) calling `seek/write` when `readyState === WRITING`, and states that `readyState` should be set to `WRITING` [as soon as the `write` function gets called](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api/#widl-FileWriter-write-void-Blob-data).
Chrome does not implement this version of the spec yet, or is still buggy, or else if would have caught your race and thrown `InvalidStateError` on the second call to `.seek()` (timeout-less version).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It helps, especially the detail of asynchronous mechanism and link providing. I finally have idea to approach my will : *1. create first, and set size to it. 2.write content to it after seek corresponding offset of each loop. 3. make synchronous between 1.&2.*